# C++ - Empty method causing SIGSEV signal

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm making a simple deck/card/hand object oriented system for a university assignment, and I've become stuck on this problem.

I've set up a simple test class which calls various methods in objects.

```
int main() {
Deck deck = Deck();
deck.DisplayDeck();
deck.Shuffle();
deck.DisplayDeck();
Hand hand = Hand(1);
Card* card;
card = deck.DealNextCard();
hand.AddCard(card);
hand.ftring();
deck.DisplayDeck();
}
```

The problem comes at `hand.ftring()`. When I call this, it causes a segmentation fault. The weird thing is, it contains no code.

in `hand.cpp`:

```
string Hand::ftring() {
}
```

If I remove it, it runs to completion. If I add a console output to the method, it prints it and then crashes. I'm completely at a loss as to what to do, as the debugger only states

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In ?? () ()
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe that `g++` still doesn't issue even a warning about this by default (MSVC treats this as an error by default for C++, a warning for C).  To get a warning about this problem (and more) use the `-Wall` option when compiling with gcc/g++.

Comment: You can also change `Hand hand = Hand(1);` to just `Hand hand(1);` and avoid an extra copy due to assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare that you are returning a string in ftring function, but you don't actually return anything. This is bad.

Comment: God damnit.

This is why I like Java/C# better. It points out when I retardedly skip over something like that! Thanks mate :)

Comment: No problem. There are lots of gotcha's with C++; I would recommend setting your compiler options to maximum strictness and convert warnings to errors. That will let you catch problems sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Your method must return a `string` - this is the way you've declared it. You're getting undefined behavior.